# jQuery, run function on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this price slider and i want it to run a certain function upon change in the slider. I want to run function filterBy on change at slider.

filterBy function

```
<script>
function filterBy() { 
$('.searchtable').addClass('hide');
$('.spinner').removeClass('hide');

$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: {'name':'<?php echo strval($_GET['name']); ?>','arrival':'<?php echo strval($_GET['arrival']); ?>','departure':'<?php echo strval($_GET['departure']);?>','guests':'<?php echo strval($_GET['guests']);?>','minRate':$( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ),'propertyCategory':$("#hotelType input[type='checkbox']:checked").val(),'minStarRating':$("#hotelRating input[type='checkbox']:checked").val(),'amenities':$("#hotelAmenities input[type='checkbox']:checked").val()},
        url: '<?php echo $baseUrl ?>/hotels/hotelFilterResult.php',


        success: function (data) {
            alert('data loaded succesfully');
            alert(this.url);

            $('.searchtable').replaceWith(data);
            $('.spinner').addClass('hide');
            $('.searchtable').removeClass('hide');

        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert('data not loaded');
        }
  });

}
</script>
```

Function for slider:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
  range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 5000,
  values: [ 500, 2000 ],
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " kr" + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] + " kr" );
  },
    change: function(event, ui) {
    filterBy();
}
});
$( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + " kr" +
  " - " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) + " kr" );
});
</script>
```

The function I want to run upon change is filterBy()
How do I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To listen [`slidechange`](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change) event of the slider you need to provide `change` configuration option:

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 5000,
    values: [500, 2000],
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val(ui.values[0] + " kr" + " - " + ui.values[1] + " kr");
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        filterBy();
    }
});
```

Alternatively you can explicetly bind to this event:

```
$("#slider-range").on("slidechange", function(event, ui) {
    filterBy();
});
```

Comment: I was just adding the `change` method to my answer, but you posted before I finished, +1, it's probably more what the OP is looking for than the `slide` handler which fires continously when sliding.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.change`

```
$( "#slider-range" ).change(function(){
   filterBy();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#slider-range" ).change(filterBy());
                                    ^^
```

There's your problem. The parantheses are executing the `filterBy` function and passing the *result* of `filterBy` into the change function (which is probably `undefined` if you don't `return` anything). What you want is to pass the `filterBy` function directly to the `change()` function like so:

```
$( "#slider-range" ).change(filterBy);

function filterBy(event) {
   // do stuff when the slider changes
}
```